# Function App deployment succeeds but fails to import packages (python, linux, consumption plan)

Tags: python, linux, azure-functions, consumption

Local deployment directly of a function app using vscode succeeds and the function app works, however when trying to build and deploy through Azure Devops, the deployment succeeds but there is an error when importing numpy.

```
Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy: IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE! Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was installed. We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html Please note and check the following: * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/usr/local/bin/python" * The NumPy version is: "1.25.0" and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help. Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' . Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
```

azure-pipelines.yml is very similar to examples, install dependencies and zip:

```
variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'azureSubscription'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-20.04'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.x' # string. Required. Version spec. Default: 3.x.
        architecture: 'x64' # 'x86' | 'x64'. Required. Architecture. Default: x64.

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

    - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'azureSubscription'
        appType: 'functionAppLinux'
        appName: 'app-name'
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

The code is then deployed to the function:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'azureSubscription'
    appType: functionAppLinux
    appName: 'app-name'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Function App/drop/*zip'
    deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
```

Any help much appreciated, have spent hours looking at examples and reading through the documentation but still haven't got this working. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve your  error make sure you have

```py
The NumPy version is: "1.25.0
```

specified in your requirements.txt file in your Azure Function repository. And In your YAML Script set the Python version in UsePythonVersion@0 to 3.10 like my script below:-

**My requirements.txt:-**

```
azure-functions
numpy==1.25.0
```

[image]

**My YAML pipeline script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'subscription-id'

  
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc56'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I adapted the pipeline code to follow your format and it now works. I think the bash line for installing the packages to the correct place made the difference.