# Azure Function App Error: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory',

Tags: python, pandas, linux, numpy, azure-functions

I am building an Azure Function app with pyhton (3.10.9) and get the following error from the app after deployment. I suspect the error is due to the operating system of the function app, which is Linux and does not support the "add_dll_directory" method used by numpy in pandas. When im debugging the app in Visual Studio it works fine. Any suggestion to how I can solve this?

Code:

```
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="myTimer")
@app.schedule(schedule="*/15 * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True, use_monitor=False)

def main(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    from batch_functions import price_data_download, position_data_download, trade_history_download, risk_checks
    import logging

    price_data_download()
    position_data_download()
    risk_checks()
    trade_history_download()
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

```
Result: Failure Exception: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 479, 
in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", 
line 58, 
in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 752, 
in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, 
in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/function_app.py", line 9, 
in main from batch_functions import price_data_download, position_data_download, trade_history_download, risk_checks File "/home/site/wwwroot/batch_functions.py", line 1, 
in <module> import pandas as pd File "/home/site/wwwroot/pandas/__init__.py", line 24, 
in <module> __import__(_dependency) File "/home/site/wwwroot/numpy/__init__.py", line 112, 
in <module> _delvewheel_patch_1_5_1() File "/home/site/wwwroot/numpy/__init__.py", line 109, in _delvewheel_patch_1_5_1 os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to install Numpy correctly in Azure Function app, Use **`numpy==1.25.0`** in your requirements.txt to install Numpy correctly like below:-

Refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76709255/function-app-deployment-succeeds-but-fails-to-import-packages-python-linux-co/76709574#76709574) for the similar issue with numpy library

**requirements.txt:-**

```
numpy==1.25.0
pandas
azure-functions
```

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import os
import sys
import azure.functions as func
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Add the directory containing numpy DLLs to the DLL search path
dll_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(np.__file__), 'DLLs')
os.add_dll_directory(dll_dir)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        # Your code that uses numpy and pandas here
        data = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3], 'Column2': [4, 5, 6]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        result = df.to_json()
        
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Data: {result}", mimetype="application/json")
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Http Trigger was deployed correctly like below:-***

[image]

**My App Files has **`numpy==1.25.0`** imported:-**

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer! I tried it by importing and adding to os in my function_app.py file, and specified numpy1.25.0 in my requirements.txt file, but still gets the same error. Where in my code should I import numpy and add dll_directory? I all .py files where pandas are used? (added functions_app.py to question above)