# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory' when importing "pandas" library in Azure Function

Tags: python, pandas, azure, ubuntu, azure-functions

I'm endeavoring to deploy an Azure Function application that relies on various libraries, including numpy, torch, and pandas (you can find all the prerequisites listed in the attached image). While the application runs smoothly on my **Ubuntu 22.0.4** laptop, I encounter a persistent issue upon deployment to the remote Azure Function. Specifically, I keep receiving the following error:

> "AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'."

I've provided an image displaying these errors for your reference.

In my attempts to resolve this issue, I explored several solutions available online, such as those outlined in [https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1462](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/answers/questions/1434854/attributeerror-module-os-has-no-attribute-add-dll) and [Azure Function App Error: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory',](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244413/azure-function-app-error-attributeerror-module-os-has-no-attribute-add-dll), yet none have proven effective thus far. Additionally, I verified that the init.py file within my local pandas installation does not include a line **invoking _delvewheel_patch_1_5_1()**. Consequently, I suspect that the problem might stem from using an *incorrect version* of *pandas* intended for *Windows rather than Linux*.

[image]

Comment: Pls post the line of code that gives this error

Comment: The problem is that the azure build is calling a pandas line that does not exist in our project, it is an empty line. The pandas that Azure has is Windows pandas, not the Linux pandas that we have, we need Linux pandas, so it's not a code problem, it's a service problem that at some point it imports the wrong pandas.  In other words, there is no such "line that is causing the error"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using latest version of modules. `.dll` file is available inside your azure function files and at mentioned path.

In Azure your local path will not work.

I have tried using method `add_dll_directory` in my simple Http trigger code, which worked for me.
**#My Directory:**

```
Myfunction/
├── HttpTrigger1/
│  ├── __init__.py
│  ├── function.json
│  └── Dll1.dll
│
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
└── requirements.txt
├── ...
```

**`__init__.py`:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

try:
    current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    dllpath = os.path.join(current_path,'Dll1.dll')
    os.add_dll_directory(dllpath)
except AttributeError:
    pass

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'column': array})

    response = f"Array: {array}\n\nDataFrame:\n{dataframe}"

    return func.HttpResponse(
        response,
        mimetype="text/plain",
        status_code=200
    )
```

**`reuirements.txt`:**

```
azure-functions
numpy
pandas
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that the function "add_dll_directory" does not exist in the library 'os'  because my function is running in Linux. It has not sense that pandas call that function in this case.

Comment: @ArthurVaz In Azure Python function has Linux platform only [image](https://i.imgur.com/6njnaft.png)

Comment: Yes, I know. But i fo not wnat to use os.add_all_direcoty() function. It is panda who is making this call. The function get the exception in line "import panda as pd"

Comment: Use latest version `Panads` . check [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/)

Comment: @ArthurVaz Could you please share your code?

Comment: We've conducted tests using pandas 2.1.3, and unfortunately, the same issue persists. The error seems to originate from a part of our code that remains unidentified. Given the extensive nature of our codebase with thousands of lines, pinpointing the specific section to display is challenging.